# Save WebView display data status between fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, webview

I have an `Activity` with some fragments and one of them shows my company's site in a `WebView`. I have been reading about how to save/restore the status of a WebView and it seems that `WebView.saveStatus(Bundle)` and `WebView.restoreStatus(Bundle)` methods are not quite reliable and, moreover, they don't store display data, so I decided not to use this way.

Now, I save the last url visited in a variable in `onPause` and then load this url in `onCreateView`.

```
    private String lastUrl = "http://www.mycompany.com";

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        lastUrl = webview.getUrl();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        contentView = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        if (contentView == null) {
            contentView = inflater.inflate(layout.extranet_fragment, container, false);
        }

        webview = (WebView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.extranet_webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl(lastUrl);

        return contentView;
    }
```

It is working properly, but now I need to save the status of a single-paged web application. Then, when I navigate through the web, the url is always `http://www.mycompany.com/#`.

How could save/restore this status?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a webClient and implement shouldOverrideUrlLoading to intercept all the urls before the WebView loads them.

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

// ASSIGN THIS URL to your **lastUrl** variable
       // Here put your code
          Log.d("My Webview", url);

       // return true; //Indicates WebView to NOT load the url;
          return false; //Allow WebView to load url
    }
});
```

#### START EDIT

```
@Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

            System.out.println("your current url when webpage loading.." + url);
        }
```

#### END EDIT

Also you can handle back press inside webview like this

```
 if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                mWebView.goBack();
            }
```

Use above code in your onBackPress method of activity or fragment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Since web is a single-paged one, WebView don't handle URLs when I navigate. The URL is always the same, so `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` is just called the first time that the website is loaded.

Comment: @bigdestroyer please check the edit and let me know if it works.

Comment: @bigdestroyer instead of loading saved url in onCreateView, try loading it in onResume  & check. Also add Null check before loading. i.e. 
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
!TextUtils.isEmpty(lastUrl)
webview.loadUrl(lastUrl);
}

Comment: My problem is that when I navigate through the website the URL is always the same, it doesn't change. Then, how can I save the status at one point? I can just save the last url visited, since URL will be always the same -> `www.mycompany.com`

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
        }

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```